# Electrostatic forces and capacitance

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, capacitance

I wonder about an example of electrostatic forces in general vs a capacitor. I sketched it out below. If I have a capacitor within a circuit, and the circuit has a power supply. And, then place a second capacitor (that is part of a circuit without a power supply, but with a volt meter) so that one plate of the second capacitor is parallel with one of the plates of the first capacitor. Will the electrostatic repulsive force experienced by this plate of the second capacitor, relate to distance by $1/d$, as in capacitance, or $1/d^2$, as in Coulomb's law.

[image]

Comment: It will feel basically nothing. The picture that is drawn on the charged capacitor is very misleading. The charges are vastly mostly on the inner surfaces, and the E fields will spill out only a tiny amount out of the capacitor.